# How to correctly type/type-check PayloadAction with React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> payload?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I'm trying to incorporate Material UI's [responsive app bar](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-responsive-menu) example into a React Typescript project. It requires identifying, based on a click event, an element to which the menu can be anchored. Their example uses `React.useState()` to store the element, whereas I am using a Redux slice and reducer. While the types in their [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3gbzw?file=/demo.tsx) and my code seem to align, I am getting an assignment type error related to `WritableDraft`.

Their code (edited for clarity):

```
const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

const handleOpenNavMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
};

const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
  setAnchorElNav(null);
};
```

My code:

```
export interface AppState {
    navAnchor: HTMLElement | null
}

const initialState: AppState = {
    navAnchor: null
}

export const appSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'app',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setNavAnchor: (state, action: PayloadAction<React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>>) => {
            state.navAnchor = action.payload.currentTarget;  // <--- this is where the error occurs
        },
        clearNavAnchor: (state) => {
            state.navAnchor = null; // <-- no error here
        }
    }
})
```

The error:

```
Type 'EventTarget & HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLElement> | null'.
  Type 'EventTarget & HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLElement>'.
    Types of property 'offsetParent' are incompatible.
      Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | null'.
        Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element>'.
          Types of property 'attributes' are incompatible.
            Type 'NamedNodeMap' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<NamedNodeMap>'.
              'number' index signatures are incompatible.
                Type 'Attr' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Attr>'.
                  The types of 'ownerDocument.anchors' are incompatible between these types.
                    Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAnchorElement>>'.
```

`'EventTarget & HTMLElement'` is clearly not the same as `HTMLElement`, but these are the same types used in the MUI example. And then a more inner line of that error stack says `Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | null'.` which is confusing because if I directly assign `null`, there's no issue.

I have tried a few different type and null checking approaches I saw in similar questions, but no dice.

I'm clearly misunderstanding something fundamental about `WritableDraft`, `HTMLElement`, or both, but I'm really struggling to find information that clears it up. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I worked around this by only sending the element Id in the event handler, and then doing a `document.getElementById()` where the actual element is needed, but I'd still be interested in any suggestions on the original question.

Comment: Does using `return { ...state, navAnchor: action.payload.currentTarget }` for the `setNavAnchor` reducer work?  I've run into something similar and that removed the error, but not sure if that's the best way.